# common positive divisors of exponential numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do we find the number of common positive divisors of two exponential numbers such as $80^{17}$ and $10^{17}$?

Comment: **Hint:** Any number that divides both $a$ and $b$ divides the greatest common divisor $\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Since $10^{17}\mid80^{17}$, it's just all of the divisors of $10^{17}$, i.e., $18^2=324$.

Comment: In turns, the [number of divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) $\sigma_0(n)$ of the number $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\ldots p_k^{a_k}$, with $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ different prime numbers, can be computed by $\sigma_0(n)=(a_1+1)(a_2+1)...(a_k+1)$. In your case $n=10^{17}=2^{17}5^{17}$. Therefore, $\sigma_0(10^{17})=(17+1)^2$

Comment: @WilliamElliot If you don't know how to compute go study it ... on your own. I am not interested in tutoring at that level.

Comment: @WilliamElliot $2 = 2^1\implies \omega(2) = 1, a_1 = 1$. Therefore, $\sigma_0(2) = \prod_{i = 1}^1 (a_i + 1) = (a_1 + 1) = 1 + 1 = 2$. That is, the number of divisors of $2$ is $2$, _not_ $3$. See the link shared by MoonLightSyzygy.